# Detect misscall on a particular number in android

Tags: android

Can anybody please tell me? I am making a sample and want to detect  miss call on a particular number. Suppose I opened the dialler with the number (0123456789) and when call on this number then detect missed call on this number. how can I do that. Please help ..

Answer (score 2):

Check the flowing code ->

In your broadcast receiver check that if the call  is received or not. Then you can find the call status.

```
public class CallBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static boolean isMissedCall;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {
            if (bundle != null) {

                String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    // Ringing
                    isMissedCall = true;
                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    // Call Received
                    isMissedCall = false;
                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    // Call Drop
                    // If don't receive call then it will be missed call
                    if(isMissedCall){
                        // do your code for missed call
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }
}
```